# Using HTTPS over HTTP for requests between servers in a subnet AWS?

Tags: networking, ssh, https, amazon-web-services, subnet

Are there any reasons to use HTTPS instead of HTTP for requests between my servers running in a private subnet on AWS?

All requests going in/out of the subnet will done via HTTPS to prevent sniffing. Is there anything to worry for requests within a subnet? Does it being a private vs public subnet affect the reasons?

Comment: at its most fundamental, your IP network is not private, because it is in someone else control on someone else's physical network. Additionally, it is likely that their network is controlled/managed via Software Defined Networking, which means that your private subnet is not likely actually on the same physical network at all. You sound like you are thinking about cloud services the way you would think about a physical router-on-a-stick network, with one pathway in/out, and private cable plant connecting everything in between. Thats not the way cloud works.

Comment: @FrankThomas that's true. If I use security groups, then is it safe to trust AWS will prevent non-AWS sources from sniffing etc.? 
Also VPCs are region specific, would it be safe to assume all machines within a VPC on AWS would be within the same physical location and not rely on public infrastructure to communicate between them?